# Regular Expressions in python to extract phone numbers of a specific format from clipboard

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I've been trying to do a personal project (a specialized version of project 1 from the book Automate boring stuff with Python but specifically to extract phone numbers of the format in my country)
The acceptable formats are:
Cellphone numbers-
(+91 or 91)optional,maybe or may not be enclosed in parenthesis
followed by an optional space(\s)? followed by the 10 digit number
Landline numbers-
3 digit area code (\d\d\d)?optional 
followed by a space or hyphen(\s or -)optional
followed by the 8 digit number
Landline numbers with country code-
(+91 or 91)optional,maybe or may not be enclosed in parenthesis
followed by (\s or -)optional
followed by 2-digit code (\d\d)
followed by (\s or -)optional
followed by the 8-digit number

The script I have written is -

```
import re,pyperclip,os,datetime

#Regexes for phone numbers.
cellphone = re.compile(r'((91|+91|\(+91\))?\s?\d{10})')
landline = re.compile(r'((\d{3}|\(d{3}\))?(-|\s)(\d{8}))')  
landline_with_countrycode = re.compile(r'((91|+91|\(+91\))(-|\s)(\d{2})(-|\s)?(\d{8}))')

#Taking input from clipboard
text = str(pyperclip.paste())
cell_nums = []
for groups in cellphone.findall(text):
    cell_nums.append(groups[0])
ll_nums = []
for groups in cellphone.findall(text):
    ll_nums.append(groups[0])
ll_nums_wccode = []
for groups in cellphone.findall(text):
ll_nums_wccode.append(groups[0])

#Sending output to a file that was created on Desktop in folder abswpy named phnumbers.log
file_path = os.path.join("C:","Users","lenovo","Desktop","abswpy","phnumbers.log")
openFile = open(file_path,'a')
now = datetime.datetime.now()
openFile.write('______________________________________________________________________________________________________\n\n')
openFile.write('\n\n As updated on '+str(now)+'\n\n')
openFile.write('---------------------------------------------------------\n')       
openFile.write('Cellphone Numbers - \n')
for i in cell_nums:
    openFile.write(str(i))
openFile.write('---------------------------------------------------------\n')   
openFile.write('Landline Numbers - \n')
for i in ll_nums:
    openFile.write(str(i))
for i in ll_nums_wccode:
    openFile.write(str(i))
openFile.write('---------------------------------------------------------\n')
openFile.write('Process Completed') 
openFile.write('______________________________________________________________________________________________________\n\n')    
openFile.close()
print "Numbers extracted if present\n"
```

The code gives compile-time error-

```
 File "regex.py", line 22, in <module>
     cellphone = re.compile(r'((91|+91|\(+91\))?\s?\d{10})')
 File "E:\Python 2_7_11\lib/re.py", line 194, in compile
     return _compile(pattern, flags)
 File "E:\Python 2_7_11\lib/re.py", line 251, in _compile
     raise error, v # invalid expression
 sre_constants.error : nothing to repeat
```

Why is my expression evaluated wrong ?
Thanks in advance for the help, I'm just a beginner!

Comment: You failed to escape `+`.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.compile(r'((91|\+91|\(\+91\))?\s?\d{10})')
                  ^      ^
```

You need to escape `+`.As `+` is a special character for regex engine.
or use `[+]`

Comment: Can you also tell me when this script runs correctly, in landline numbers(containing 8 digits at MAX) it strips a cellphone number(say 9999999999 (9*10) to 99999999(9*8) and still accepts the numer

Comment: Even on using anchors ^ and $ , I am unable to get the right output